# SSRS - list of parameters not visible after redirecting to a report

Tags: caching, reporting-services

I have two reports in SSRS - the main one with the list of parameters, and the dependant one. You can navigate between them in both ways (there are appropriate actions assigned).

The problem is that when I display the dependant report and then I come back to the main one, the list of parameters is not visible (the issue appears in Visual Studio as well as on Report Server and Sharepoint - both IE and Chrome)

I have used the "Do not cache temporary copies of this report" in report processing options.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior, Since the purpose of a drill-down report is to pass the parameters from the master report to the details report, it's not allow to see or modify the parameters in the details report.
Therefore, the parameter pane is automatically hidden in the details report.

you can use jump to URL and set the parameters to be true, like this:

http:///reportserver?/ReportFolder/Reportname&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Parameters=true

You can refer to [Using URL Access Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Works fine. Thank y ou! Some of parameters used on master report are not aimed to be passed to dependant report so I wanted them to be visible.